# htaccess - Friendly url with redirection

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been looking for several solutions on the web but as I have always had problems interpreting the htaccess, I have not achieved what I wanted.

I have a website with the following type of link:

```
https://sub.example.com/search.php?gosearch=new+music+techno
https://sub.example.com/search.php?gosearch=nice-music-rock
```

And I would like to obtain a link in this way:

```
https://sub.example.com/search/new-music-techno
```

I also have a problem, when in my form I press enter, this automatically adds the "+" symbol to all the spaces and I do not know with what method the change would be made automatically to a "-", if with PHP, with JQuery or with .htacess.

In parallel I also have this type of links:

```
https://sub.example.com/topmusic.php
```

And I would like to obtain this type of link:

```
https://sub.example.com/topmusic/
```

Is it possible to implement everything with htacess?

Do I need to make several conditions or just one?

**Is it possible that old urls are redirected automatically to the new form once the user clicks on them?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?gosearch=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

And on search.php you need to replace the code. htaccess will send the whole string next to "search/" on search.php file under gosearch $_GET parameter.